# getting binary format for displaying image in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, winforms, image

i am currently facing some problem retrieving image for display on a datagridview control.
The Image data type in the database  is blob.
 I am using mysql as a database for retrieving the image . may i ask if it is possible to just retrieve a image data of this format and display in the gridview? or do i need to store the image in a image folder for retrieval?

I am using winforms application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really think it's possible to figure out EXACT  format of the image from its binary stream. The only solution I met, is storing the format in DB too, or have architectual convension to store in DB only one format type images.

Comment: i dint find any datatype other than blob and long blob and medium blob .. can u give any sample code pls...for converting ...

Comment: @user852714 here is just one example, but you can fibd a tone out there on internet http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/321ad2bf-6c83-4ac6-b6bb-e2b8472bea30/

Answer (score 0):

Storing it in the local folder shall help you if you wish to reload it again later provided the DB isnt modified. Other wise i dont see any benefits here. Some times DB access is faster.